# How to get nested object from non-nested json with Gson.fromJson

Tags: android, gson

There is an json with dropoff location, pickup location and order information, dropoff/pickup location is not nested, but I want to deserialize to one order object, which nested pickup location model and dropoff location model. I want to auto deserialize with Gson.fromJson(). How can I reach it?

The non-nested json as following:

```
{
    dropoffAddress = "Changsha Railway Station";
    dropoffCity = Changsha;
    dropoffLoc =     (
        "113.012966",
        "28.195013"
    );
    dropoffLocation = "Changsha Railway Station Changsha";
    dropoffState = Hunan;
    orderNo = 3467;
    orderStatus = 0;
    orderTime = "2015-07-09T01:08:42.089Z";
    pickupAddress = "Yanzishan Rd";
    pickupCity = Changsha;
    pickupState = Hunan;
}
```

Order model:

```
public class OrderModel {
    String orderNo;
    String orderTime;
    int OrderStatus;
    AddressModel pickupAddress;
    AddressModel dropoffAddress;
}
```

AddressModel:

```
public class AddressModel {
    String address;
    String city;
    String location;
    String state;
    LatLng loc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented it in a hard way.

All the fields of json object is mapped to model, and then I write a getPickupAddress() and getDropoffAddress() to get related properties. Code is something as below.

```
public class OrderModel {
    String orderNo;
    String orderTime;
    int OrderStatus;
    String dropoffAddress;
    String dropoffCity;
    Double[] dropoffLoc;
    ...
    String pickupAddress;
    String pickupCity;
    Double[] pickupLoc;
    AddressModel pickupAddressModel;
    AddressModel dropoffAddressModel;

    public AddressModel getPickupAddressModel() {
        AddressModel addressModel = new AddressModel();
        addressModel.setAddress = this.pickupAddress;
        addressModel.setCity = this.pickupCity;
        ...
        return addressModel;
    }

    Public AddressModel getDropoffAddressModel() {
        AddressModel addressModel = new AddressModel();
        addressModel.setAddress = this.dropoffAddress;
        addressModel.setCity = this.dropoffCity;
        ...
        return addressModel;
    }
}
```